# Multilabel classification without using sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier

Tags: classification, python, multilabel

Could someone recommend a tutorial that shows how to solve the multilabel classification problem, by using one-vs-rest approach, but not using   sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier. The algorithm may use any binary classification method, such as tree. Any pointers much appreciated

Comment: Wikipedia gives a reasonable [description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification#One-vs.-rest)

Comment: @user20160 Thanks, but I am looking for a tutorial with code and more details. Could you recommend any?